# How to change column structure on resize

Tags: html, css, html-email

When the screen size hits 600px or lower I wanted to make the td's the width of the table, i.e. they stack vertically in one column:

https://jsfiddle.net/gkygudyp/

```
</tr>
    <td class="stack" style="background-color:yellow;">
        Hello
    </td>
    <td class="stack" style="background-color:orange;">
        Hello
    </td>
</tr>

.stack {
      width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: You should use divs with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Tables just aren't meant to be used like that and probably won't for that reason.

Comment: I can't use divs for html email.

Comment: ah, sorry. I didn't notice that tag.

Comment: Please make sure that your HTML is valid. I see not opened `tr`'s .

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/). Look at the section titled "Building responsive layouts." It looks like it is exactly what you are looking for. Instead of using td they use whole tables as columns using the `align` attribute. As I said, you can't stack `td`s. Then they use a media query to cause it to stack at certain screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, most modern web standards are not supported by many email clients, making such responsive design difficult or impossible. Since JavaScript is not allowed by any email client (for security reasons) the only other solution here would be to use a media query such as

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Your rules here */
}
```

However, it is important to note the [email client support](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-media-queries-in-html-email) of media queries.

---

You mentioned in the comments that you can not use `div`s in HTML emails. You actually can, however, developers often opt for `table`s because while all email clients support `div`s, they do not support many CSS rules necessary to properly have a layout based on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing td to block in media querty

```
@media (max-width:600px){
    .stack{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```